# ASP.NET UpdatePanel lock all TextBox controls after post-back

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

My code behind is VB.NET. I use ASP.NET UpdatePanel like the following. However, after the post-back, it locks TextBox controls , I cannot type anything
, except when I move the mouse over and click on the TextBox.

> Can anyone show me why it locked all TextBox controls after the post-back?

Here's why I use UpdatePanel:

- During the post-back, after inserting data into DB, set all TextBox text property to String.Empty
- After the form is submitted, the Panel pStudent should be refresh , not the entire page
- and the TextBox txtId should be in focus again.

here's the mark-up of the ASP.NET page: http://pastebin.com/maSN8mjj

Comment: What do you mean by "except when I move the mouse over and click on the TextBox"? This is default behaviour when controls don't have the focus.

Comment: After the post-back, I set focus on TextBox txtId. The cursor is there in the TexBox but it won't accept any input, only when I move the mouse and click in the TextBox first, then it will accept input. This is very strange problem that occurred to me. I used UpdatePanel before many time, but I never have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, it was Me.Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off") that was in the Page Load event to turn off the TextBox control history.

Now, I moved it to :

```
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            Me.Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off")

      End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to set focus to the TextBox? It seems whatever method you are using is not being fired after the UpdatePanel is refreshed. I have had other issues with javascript not being applied to elements within an UpdatePanel.

Makesure your js that changes focus fires after the UpdatePanel is refreshed so the focus returns to your TextBox.